# Writing / Reading Value to an Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I must be going insane. This is incredibly simple so I am apparently overlooking something:

Here is my code:

---

```
int salesarray[20];    
scanf("%d",&sales_input);    
printf("sales_input is %d",sales_input);    
salesarray[i] = sales_input;    
printf("salesValue is %d",i,salesarray[i]);
```

Here is what I will see:

sales_input is 2salesValue is 1

Can anyone explain why my array is not being updated properly? salesValue should be changing to the value 2. Or I am reading it wrong here...

Comment: The %d in your second printf prints the value of i, not salesarray[i].

Comment: I'm sorry everyone -- I confused myself here since its so late. Everyone is right -- I should be just using printf("text",salesarray[i]);

My fault for copying my own code from a previous project and then failing to carefully inspect it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix this:

```
printf("salesValue is %d",i,salesarray[i]);
```

shouldn't it be?

```
printf("salesValue is %d", salesarray[i]);
```

Comment: What is wrong with it? I'm sorry -- its 3:36 AM, I must not be seeing something here.

Comment: @BSchlinker, you want to output i or salesarray[i] ?

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("salesValue is %d",i,salesarray[i]);
```

is missing a %d (you are not printing the salesarray value at all):

```
printf("salesValue is %d %d",i,salesarray[i]);
```

Try compiling with -Wall -Werror to make warnings into errors. -Werror would have showing you the problem from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to print `i` or `salesarray[i]`?
You only have a single `%d` in the printf "format string" ...

```
printf("salesValue is %d",i,salesarray[i]);
/*                        ^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
```